# Running asyncio loop and tkinter gui

Tags: python, tkinter, python-asyncio

How do I run a asyncio loop running a while loop for websocket receiving and tkinter gui at the same time?

My current code: (without GUI)

I know how to write the code for tkinter gui but getting problems when compining them. When starting tkinter Mainloop the asyncio loop stops and disconnects from websocket. I also tried threading but hasent worked either.

```
import asyncio
import websockets
from aioconsole import ainput

queue = asyncio.Queue()


async def connect():
    global name
    try:
        async with websockets.connect("ws://ip:port") as websocket:
            print("Verbunden!")
            
            asyncio.get_running_loop().create_task(send(websocket))
            asyncio.get_running_loop().create_task(cli())

            while True:
                message = await websocket.recv()
                print(message)


    except:
        print("Fehler!")
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        asyncio.get_running_loop().stop()


async def send(websocket):
    print("Sender gestartet!")
    global name
    while True:
        message = await queue.get()
        await websocket.send(message)


async def cli():
    print("Bereit für Eingabe!")
    while True:
        message = await ainput()
        await queue.put(message)



loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(connect())
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: Can you please show your attempt when using `threading`? I don't know much about `asyncio`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a working solution using threading, asyncio and websockets:

```
import tkinter
import asyncio
import threading
import websockets
from websockets import exceptions
import json
from datetime import datetime


# Starthilfe für asynkrone Funktion connect
def _asyncio_thread():
    async_loop.create_task(connect())
    async_loop.run_forever()


async def connect():
    try:
        async with websockets.connect("ws://194.163.132.218:8765") as websocket:
            while True:
                message = await websocket.recv()
                print(message)


async def send(websocket, name):
    while True:
        message = await queue.get()
        await websocket.send(msg)

def buttonexecutor(e=None):
    msg = entry.get()
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(messagesender(msg), async_loop)
    entry.delete(0, "end")


async def messagesender(message):
    await queue.put(message)


def logger(reason, message):
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    text.configure(state="normal")
    text.insert("end", f"({current_time}) [ {reason} ] {message}\n")
    text.configure(state="disabled")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Asyncio
    async_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    queue = asyncio.Queue()

    # Erstelle tkinter
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.title("Messanger")

    text = tkinter.Text(root, width=150, state="disabled")
    text.pack()

    entry = tkinter.Entry(root, state="disabled", width=100)
    entry.pack()

    tkinter.Button(master=root, text="Senden", command=buttonexecutor).pack()

    # Starte Websocket Verbindung
    thread = threading.Thread(target=_asyncio_thread).start()

    # Starte tkinter
    root.mainloop()
```